# Can't Longpolling Telegram

Tags: php, curl, telegram

I can't make LongPolling query to Telegram.

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

(intval($this->offset) !== 0) ? $post_data['offset'] = $this->offset : NULL;

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $this->api_url . $this->method,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 0,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST            => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $post_data,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

`api_url` is correct, method is `getUpdates` so should be ok, but Telegram returns me immediately with empty result like this:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["ok"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["result"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? As i know - query should not return me empty result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Telegram docs have misunderstanding in decalration of argument timeout.

```
timeout - Timeout in seconds for long polling. Defaults to 0, i.e. usual short polling. Should be positive, short polling should be used for testing purposes only.
```

Add **POST** attribute `timeout > 0` for `getUpdates` query to make it long polling.

Answer (score 0):

PHP **CAN NOT** be long polling client.

You have 2 solution:

1. Use infinite loop contains normal `getUpdates` method.
2. If your host provider offered public HTTPS service, use [Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) instead of polling.

Comment: It can. Long polling technology concerns how server is returning result, which language you gonna use to fetch results doesn't matter. So if i add `timeout` to my query, it will be long polling, as i wrote above.

Comment: Why it couldn't be used for long polling?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, buy maybe this could help someone. Actually with ReactPHP you can use long polling mode with PHP. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/badfarm/zanzara).